# It does not return the language correctly when the locale.getDisplayName function is called

Tags: java, locale

I am programming a web-service for an application developed in Liferay. The problem I am having is that when I am going to call a function of the REST API created for the return of languages, it gives problems in one of them.

This method makes a call to the Java default `locale.getDisplayName (locale)` which returns the name of the language. In my case, I have three languages: **Spanish, English** and **Portuguese**.

For the first two languages I pass the corresponding `locale` and it returns the name of the correct language:

- `es` returns **Spanish** - correct
- `en` returns **English** - correct

However, when I pass Portuguese `pt`, it returns **English (United States)** instead of **Portuguese**

**Why does it return "English" instead of "Portuguese"?**

This is the java version installed on the server:

> openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-8u232-b09-1~deb9u1-b09)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)

**EDIT** *code from the comments:*

```
Locale leng = LocaleUtil.fromLanguageId(i.getIdiomaId()); 
String idiomCap = leng.getDisplayName(leng);
```

`LocaleUtil` is a **Liferay** class that is used to collect the language ids that are added to Liferay in its configuration. In this case I would return an array with the id "es", "en" and "pt" `getDisplayName(leng)` is from Java `Locale`

Comment: How **exactly** do you pass `"pt"`? Can you show it please?

Comment: `Locale.forLanguageTag("pt").getDisplayName()` **is** returning `"Portuguese"` (JDK 1.8.0_141 or/and OpenJDK 13)

Comment: Even `Locale pt = new Locale("pt");` makes `pt.getDisplayName();` return `Portuguese` or the equivalent depending on the default locale of the system.

Comment: Please update your question and add the  code that returns the wrong language and also show us how you call that method.

Comment: I've seen that you probably are passing an additional argument to `getDisplayName` - that argument is not the locale for which you want to display the language, it is the locale in which language the result is presented (e.g. `Locale.forLanguageTag("pt").getDisplayName(Locale.GERMAN)` will return `"Portugiesich"`)

Comment: Please take the time to edit your question, respond to comments  and maybe even accept answers. If you continue ignoring your posts or other people's comments, I am afraid, people will just stop answering.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers,

Locale leng = LocaleUtil.fromLanguageId (i.getIdiomaId ());
String idiomCap = leng.getDisplayName (leng);
LocaleUtil is a Liferay class that is used to collect the language ids that are added to Liferay in its configuration. In this case I would return an array with the id "es", "en" and "pt" getDisplayName (leng) is from Java Locale

Comment: This is a great showcase for the evil nature of crossposts. Please don't crosspost to different places, and definitely not without linking the posts to each other. [Read this question and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/) for the reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find any usable javadoc for `LocaleUtil`, only empty stubs. Examining the source code I found:

- `fromLanguageId(String)` ends up calling the three argument version having

  - `validate = true`: only return available languages and
  - `useDefault = true`: use default if not available or unknown
- default is `Locale("en", "US")` if not changed (`setDefault()`)

I suppose that Portuguese is not available and the  method is returning `Locale("en",`"US")`, but I have no idea what *available*  means in that context - I could not find any documentation (too lazy to really search for it or examine more source code) - there should be a LOG entry about the invalid language if warning is enabled.

You can try to use the 3 argument version of that method, passing `useDefault = false` - it should return `null` if the language is not available.

```java
LocaleUtil.fromLanguageId(i.getLanguageId(), true, false);
```

You can also pass `validate = false`, which disables availability checking, but not sure if that makes much sense - you could use `Locale.fromLanguageId()` instead.